# How to crop image in Titanium mobile Application

Tags: titanium

I have implemented crop functionality but
Is it possible to selection crop image like below link
http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=advanced

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, not really unless you do some clever coding and view aligning / transforming.

Long answer, you have two options:

1. Create your own custom module with XCode, OBJ-C etc.
2. Just nest the Jcrop code in your own webview inside titanium. (This seems easiest).